# Ubuntu 17.10 upgrade from 17.04 - Power Off, Suspend, Hibernate, Network Settings Change, System Settings - ALL HANG!

Tags: networking, network-manager, suspend, power-management, hibernate

I upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 recently on my Acer Aspire E15 (model: E5-574G-54Y2) and have following problems.

1. Can't change wifi settings (I was able to connect to one of my WiFi networks), sometimes I can see rest of the WiFi networks but any attempt to change it hangs the entire system (System Settings App included). Even Power-Off, Suspend seem to hang forever.
2. Same goes for the Wired Network. Any changes to it, ends in same result at 1. above.
3. Power-off, Suspend, Resume, Hibernate all fail miserably. If I do not make any changes, I can power-off the laptop by simply waiting for 60 seconds and watch the counter go down. If I click on Power Off button, it never shuts down.
4. System Settings App hangs frequently, usually after any change. And then any of power down options stop working.

I have surfed the web and tried all suggestions to clean-up, update packages, created a larger swapfile (12GB) instead of swap partition but none of this seems to make any difference.

Could it be that some of the older packages are still lingering around and causing a conflict? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Rest of the system is working great (no nvidia drivers, wireless, wired network issues - that is if I do not make any changes!).

Thank you!